# How to change default Photoshop CS4 resolution to 96 dpi?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Using Adobe Photoshop CS4 on Windows, it defaults the resolution on new images to being 72 dpi, but I want 96 dpi.  How can I configure Photoshop so that 96 dpi is the default instead of 72 dpi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `Edit` on the menu bar and go down to `Preferences > Units & Rulers`, you can then set the `New Document Preset Resolutions` here.

[image]